# Fast way to convert strings to numbers on large dataset

Tags: python-2.7, hashtable, categorical-data

I have a data set with tens of millions of rows. Several columns on this data represent categorical features. Each level of these features is represented by an alpha-numeric string like "b009d929".

```
C1        C2        C3        C4        C5        C6        C7      
68fd1e64  80e26c9b  fb936136  7b4723c4  25c83c98  7e0ccccf  de7995b8 ...  
68fd1e64  f0cf0024  6f67f7e5  41274cd7  25c83c98  fe6b92e5  922afcc0
```

I'd like to to be able to use Python to map each distinct level to a number to save memory. So that feature C1's levels would be replaced by numbers from 1 to C1_n, C2's levels would be replaced by numbers from 1 to C2_n...
Each feature has different number of levels, ranging from under 10 to 10k+.
I tried dictionaries with Pandas' .replace() but it gets extremely slow.
What is a fast way to approach this problem?

Comment: I feel like using a lightweight [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) like [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) that is properly [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would be ideal for this use case, especially if you want to start querying on it. Pandas even has [support](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Chapter%209%20-%20Loading%20data%20from%20SQL%20databases.ipynb) for using databases as the data source.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the categorical features values were hashed onto 32 bits. So I ended up reading the file in chunks and applying this simple function

```
int(categorical_feature_value, 16)
```